# How to access related entities in a form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am currenty struggling with the forms and the held entities, because I am not able to access attributes from a related entity within a form.

```
form.get('value') // access current entity
form.get('value').relatedEntity  // (access the related entity)
form.get('value').relatedEntity.property // is not working
```

---

I would like to explain my whole scenario more in a detail, because I think my current solution is not the best and maybe I can avoid the whole issue with designing my forms a little bit different.

I basically followed the instruction on how to submit multiple entities within one form https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/symfony2/DjwwzOfUIuQ%5B1-25%5D

First, here are my Entities:

```
//@ORM\Entity
class Game {

    //@ORM\Column(name="scoreT1", type="integer", nullable=true)
    private $scoreT1;

    //@ORM\Column(name="scoreT2", type="integer", nullable=true)
    private $scoreT2;


    //@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Bet", mappedBy="game")
    private $bet;
}
```

```php
//@ORM\Entity
class Bet {
    //@ORM\Column(name="scoreT1", type="integer", nullable=true)
    private $scoreT1;

    //@ORM\Column(name="scoreT2", type="integer", nullable=true)
    private $scoreT2;

    // @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Game", inversedBy="bet")
    private game;
}
```

And these are my Forms:

```
class GamesListType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('bets', 'collection',array(
                      'required' => false,
                      'allow_add' => false,
                      'type' => new BetType()
        ))
        ;
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Strego\TippBundle\Form\Model\BetCollection');
    }
}
```

```php
class BetType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('scoreT1')
                ->add('scoreT2');
        ;
    }

     public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Strego\TippBundle\Entity\Bet');
    }
}
```

In order to get the bets from the "mainEntity" in the GamesListForm I created a dedicated Collectionclass:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
class BetCollection extends ArrayCollection {

    public function getBets(){
        return $this;//->toArray();
    }
}
```

This is more the environment I'm working on. My requirement is to somehow show a list of games and a form to bet on this games. I currently try to achieve it like this:

```
{% for bet in form.bets %}
     bet.get('value').game.scoreT1  // <-- this is my current issue
        <div class="row">{{ form_widget(item) }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I am explaining the whole scenario, because I would like some input how to achieve the list of games and the forms next to it. Another Idea was to have 3 Forms: GamesList / Game / Bet, but somehow i ran into an endlessloop which was stopped by symfony. Is there a general issue with 3 layers in forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue was somewhere else.
Related entities and their properties can easily accessed via:

```
form.get('value').relatedEntity.property
```